Why cant I measure proper length on spacetime curvature with the following formula?

I'm struggling right now from the definition of proper length along spacetime curvature, it is said as I found online the length that object covered on his spacetime rest frame , so why cant I use the following formula for the proper length on spacetime curvature

It might help if you gave more details as to why you think this is correct and what is indicating to you that it is not correct

I think in order to non-Euclidean shape to exist it  should be inside Euclidean space that describes it , now for spacetime curvature which is totally non-Euclidean shape what is the Euclidean space that describes it and if this space depend on time what time is that

Minkowski spacetime is not embedded in a larger Euclidean spacetime, or not as far as we know. Minkowski spacetime has the signature (-+++) because that's the way spacetime is. You could have spacetimes with a (++++) signature but experiment shows our spacetime isn't like that.

@John Rennie how can't we describe non-Euclidean shape with Euclidean space , an example from what I'm saying is that earth is non-Euclidean shape that can be described totally be Euclidean space

What's being said is that spacetime (not Earth specifically) is non-euclidean, and it isn't embedded in any higher-dimensional euclidean space. If it were, you could define a way to describe spacetime with euclidean geometry, but it's not. What's wrong with your formula is that the spacelike ($\mathrm{d}x^2$, $\mathrm{d}y^2$, $\mathrm{d}z^2$) terms and the timelike term ($c^2\mathrm{d}t^2$) have the same sign. In reality, the signs must oppose each other to get the right results. Try deriving the Lorentz factor $\gamma=\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\tau}$ with your formula.
